# Does closing an event object cause threads waiting on that object to wake up?

Tags: windows

Suppose I have a Windows event object, e.g. from calling `CreateEvent`.

Thread A is blocked in `WaitForSingleObject(event_handle)`.

Thread B calls `CloseHandle(event_handle)`.

Question 1: What happens to thread A?

Question 2: Does it make a difference if Thread A is blocked in `WaitForMultipleObjects`? What does `WaitForMultipleObjects` return?

Answer (score 2):

From experimentation, it seems that `WaitForSingleObject` does *not* wake up if the handle is closed, i.e. thread A keeps waiting. I haven't checked, but I assume `WaitForMultipleObjects` is the same.

I suspect what's going on is that event objects inside the kernel are reference counted. `CloseHandle` drops a reference, but it doesn't necessarily destroy the underlying object. (For example, if multiple processes hold handles to the same object, the object isn't destroyed until all of the processes call `CloseHandle`.) And `WaitForSingleObject` also takes a reference to the object it waits for. Of course, I don't have the Windows source code so I can't confirm this for certain.

Comment: Intuitively, it makes sense that the conversion "handle to data structure internal kernel reference" is only done once, at system call entry.